# C++ utf-8 literals in GCC and MSVC

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, unicode, utf-8

Here i have some simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

    int main()
    {
         const unsigned char utf8_string[] = u8"\xA0";
         std::cout << std::hex << "Size: " << sizeof(utf8_string) << std::endl;
          for (int i=0; i < sizeof(utf8_string); i++) {
            std::cout << std::hex << (uint16_t)utf8_string[i] << std::endl;
          }
    }
```

I see different behavior here with MSVC and GCC.
MSVC sees `"\xA0"` as not encoded unicode sequence, and encodes it to utf-8.
So in MSVC the output is:

> C2A0

Which is correctly encoded in utf8 unicode symbol `U+00A0`.

But in case of GCC nonthing happens. It treats string as simple bytes. There's no change even if i remove `u8` before string literal.

Both compilers encode to utf8 with output `C2A0` if the string is set to: `u8"\u00A0";`

Why do compilers behave differently and which actually does it right?

Software used for test:

> GCC 8.3.0
>
> MSVC 19.00.23506

C++ 11

Comment: What are you getting as output on MSVC (PS: I don't have it)? On `g++` and `clang` I am getting this: `Size: 2 
a0 
0`.

Comment: The *output* of `u8` is standard, it must be UTF-8. But the interpretation of the *input* to `u8` may not be standard. The behavior of `\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX` are standard, they must be interpreted as a codepoint. But the interpretation of `\xXX` is a bit more implementation-defined, though. `\xA0` may be interpreted as a single `char` `0xA0` as-is, or it may be expanded to codepoint U+00A0 and then encoded to 2 `char`s `0xC2 0xA0`. You are seeing both behaviors.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you provide some reference for "`\xA0` may be (..) expanded to codepoint", because https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape says `\xnn` is a byte rather than a codepoint.

Comment: @MrLister cppreference.com is generally reliable but it's not infallible. Given that UTF-8 has rules for being a valid sequence of bytes, it's not unreasonable that a compiler could apply some translations if necessary.

Comment: The [character literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) `U8'\xA0'` is ill-formed (since the code point is not representable with a single UTF-8 code unit), so I'd expect a character string with such a literal would also result in an ill-formed program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're both wrong.

As far as I can tell, the C++17 standard says [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.string#15) that:

> The size of a narrow string literal is the total number of escape sequences and other characters, plus at least one for the multibyte encoding of each universal-character-name, plus one for the terminating '\0'.

Although there are other hints, this seems to be the strongest indication that escape sequences are not multi-byte and that MSVC's behaviour is wrong.

There are tickets for this which are currently marked as Under Investigation:

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/225847/hex-escape-codes-in-a-utf8-literal-are-treated-in.html
- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/260684/escape-sequences-in-unicode-string-literals-are-ov.html

However it also says [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.ccon#3) about UTF-8 literals that:

> If the value is not representable with a single UTF-8 code unit, the program is ill-formed.

Since `0xA0` is not a valid UTF-8 character, the program should not compile.

Note that:

- UTF-8 literals starting with `u8` are defined as being narrow.
- `\xA0` is an escape sequence
- `\u00A0` is considered a universal character name and not an escape sequence

Comment: "ill-formed" means that the program should not be compiled without issuing the diagnostics. The standard allows to compile such a program and calls such behavior an extension.

Comment: There's a very thin line between "it's an extension" and "it's wrong". Arguably every instance of the former is an example of the latter, from a standard perspective.

Comment: The comment about representability is in reference to character literals, this question is about string literals which have no such restriction. So there is no conflict, the second half of this answer is not relevant.

Comment: "However it also says here about UTF-8 literals that:": That quote applies only to _character literals_, not _string literals_.

Answer (score 2):

This is [CWG issue 1656](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1656).

It has been resolved in the current standard draft through [P2029R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2029r4.html) so that the numeric escape sequences are to be considered by their value as a single code unit, not as a unicode code point which is then encoded to UTF-8. This is even if it results in an invalid UTF-8 sequence.

Therefore GCC's behavior is/will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you which way is true to the standard.

The way MSVC does it is at least logically consistent and easily explainable.  The three escape sequences `\x`, `\u`, and `\U` behave identically except for the number of hex digits they pull from the input: 2, 4, or 8.  Each defines a Unicode codepoint that must then be encoded to UTF-8.  To embed a byte without encoding leads to the possibility of creating an invalid UTF-8 sequence.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do compilers behave differently and which actually does it right?

Compilers behave differently because of the way they decided to implement the C++ standard:

- GCC uses strict rules and implements the standard as is
- MSVC uses loose rules and implements the standard in a more practical "real-world" kind of way

So things that fail in GCC will usually work in MSVC because it's more permissible. And MSVC handles some of these issues automatically.

Here is a similar example:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33167.
It follows the standard, but it's not what you would expect.

As to which does it right, depends on what your definition of "right" is.

Comment: But GCC doesn't implement it as-is